# UILabel doesn't do multiline in a custom UITableViewCell on launch but does after scrolled-back

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

## edit #1

I added a link to the project on github here: 
https://github.com/trestles/testtable

This is really my first time dealing with Autolayout so I expect I am doing some amateur mistakes. Honestly, I know how I'd do this manipulating frames but can't get to work properly with autolayout with the clipping of content. Part of the questions is should I just be using frames if we are always in portrait mode?

---

I have a custom UITableViewCell where I have a few UILabels. They are set to numberOfLines=0. Sometimes, they will truncate the text. Like this:

[image]

How do I fix this? I have tried to reloadData in viewDidLoad but that didn't seem to matter. Most times, when you scroll, it fixes itself (but not always). It can be any three of the UILabels and is indepedent of the amount of text. My first time using UILabels with Auto Layout so most likely some mistake I have made. Here's what my UILabel properties are:

[image]

and the layout for the first label:

[image]

Comment: have you added '\n' to mark the end of line

Comment: my understanding is that it should wrap and that a \n is unecessary. I have set the width via a constraint. I have done a bunch of times using manual frames and multiLine is usually enabled via setting numberOfLines=0

Comment: paste some code here.

Comment: there really isn't much code. I'm trying to configure the labels via IB. I have included screenshots of the constraints.

Comment: @timpone Ok, I could not figure out the solution without your code, but I have tried to give an answer. Take a look and let me know, If it works for you. (Y)

Comment: Your view controller is showing a red arrow indicating problems with your constraints. Fix those first, then see if the problem goes away. Also, instead of setting width constraints on the labels, I would recommend setting leading/trailing constraints to the superview or neighboring labels.

Comment: thx @MikeTaverne , I fixed this. Hmmm... It doesn't look like there's an obvious fix. Here's the project code if anyone wants to take a look: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15991924/testtable.zip  thx

Comment: Try keeping a high value for Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance  - Vertical part

Comment: testtable.zip link to dropbox gives 404 error (file not found)

Comment: What's the desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **auto layout** is **perfect**, just issue occurred because you are setting `auto layout` with **default text** in your **xib**. and in you `viewDidLoad`, where you are updating `UILabel` text but not updating `layout` programatically. so just one line is left as below.

```
self.mainTV.layoutIfNeeded();
```

Add above line before reload `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad` method. all the things working fine.

**Example** :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mainTV.dataSource=self
    self.mainTV.delegate=self
    self.mainTV.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.mainTV.estimatedRowHeight = 84.0
    //self.mainTV.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")


    var tmps = [String]()

    tmps.append("ABC But here is an artist. He desires to paint you the dreamiest, shadiest, quietest, most enchanting bit of romantic landscape in all the valley of the Saco. What is the chief element he employs?")
    tmps.append("DEF But here is an artist.")
    tmps.append("GHI But here is an artist. He desires to paint you the dreamiest, shadiest, quietest, most enchanting bit")

    for var i=0; i<10; i++
    {
      var menuItem=EKMenuItem()
      let randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tmps.count)))
      menuItem.header = "\(i) \(tmps[randomIndex1])"

      let randomIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tmps.count)))
      menuItem.detail = "\(i) \(tmps[randomIndex2])"
      let randomIndex3 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tmps.count)))
      menuItem.price = "\(i) \(tmps[randomIndex3])"
      //tmpItem.price = "my price"
      dataItems.append(menuItem)
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    self.mainTV.layoutIfNeeded();
    self.mainTV.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @timpone, let me know if you still have issue.

Answer (score 2):

**update your cell constraint and layout**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomCell") as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.headerLabel.text=dataItems[indexPath.row].header
    cell.setHeader(dataItems[indexPath.row].header)
    cell.setDetail(dataItems[indexPath.row].detail)
    cell.setPrice(dataItems[indexPath.row].price)
    // update constraint and layout
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded the source from git. I'm not sure whether this is bug or not. But reloading the table in viewdidappear solved the issue.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        mainTV.reloadData()

    }
```

This is how it will look on simulator when you perform above operation.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add `self.mainTV.reloadData()` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can solve your problem.

You can see more detail here.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html

Answer (score 0):

I see you set constraint only in height, no width.
Try setting it also.